# Visual studio add-in to simplify editing command line arguments

Tags: .net, visual-studio, add-in, command-line-arguments

The command line arguments editor on the project properties page for C# and other projects is horribly tiny and difficult to work with. You crtl-a for instance does not select all the lines. Is there an add-in to simplify command line arguments editing?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is: check out CLI args ([http://n0n4m3.codingcorner.net/?p=214](http://n0n4m3.codingcorner.net/?p=196))
It is very useful when you have to test or run your program with different sets of command line arguments.

> "Command Line Arguments Made Easy (CLIArgsMadeEasy) is a Visual Studio
>   Add-in that eases the access and change of the startup project’s
>   command line arguments. Instead of having to go to project properties
>   or instead of using the command window to run your program with
>   different arguments, CLIArgsMadeEasy adds a field in the toolbar for
>   you to edit and saves everything you enter. A button is also added
>   that opens a console window in the project’s working directory or home
>   directory (if there’s no working directory set for this project)."

Answer (score 1):

Here's another tool that makes this easy: SetProjectCommandLineArguments2013 and 2012 on Visual Studio Gallery (http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/efc96e64-b041-41f3-b528-f93f6fcf34ca)

It is a Visual Studio extension that contains a command that executes Edit.Copy and then pastes the clipboard contents into the command line arguments of the current startup project. To use it I add a text file to my project or solution, add and edit the command arguments in that text file, position my cursor on the line containing the arguments I want to use, and press the shortcut Shift-Alt-5. That copies the current line and sets the current startup project's command line property to the copied string.

Answer (score 0):

Do you seriously spend so much time with it that you need a special editor or add-in for it?

<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Arrow</kbd> selects text fine, as does <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>mouse click</kbd>. As for an editor, you can use Notepad, or Notepad++.

But having said that, the best editor is right under your nose - just open a text file in Visual Studio, edit away, then copy/paste your text into the box. If you want to avoid copy/pasting then follow these steps:

- in the Solution Explorer, right click on the project, select *Open Folder in Windows Explorer*
- in the resulting Explorer window, drag and drop the `csproj.user` file for your project back into the VS IDE (assuming you are using C#, it will be *vbproj.user* if you are using VB, etc.)
- the file will be opened in the IDE; in both VS2010 and VS2008 it is in XML format and you can add your command line arguments to the `Project/PropertyGroup/StartArguments` node of the file. It doesn't get any better than that :)

Comment: Yes, unfortunately i do spend enough time with it that it annoys me.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply click (left click on the mouse) on the words "Command Arguments" - This is equal to hit "Ctrl+a" (Select all).

Now your PC will act like the whole sentence is selected.

Here are few examples - After you click "Command Arguments":

1. You can start writing, than the whole sentence will replace with you writing.
2. You can hit "Backspace" key and it will delete the whole sentence.
3. You can hit "Ctrl+X" - Than it will cut the "Command Arguments" sentence.
4. You can hit "Ctrl+C" - Than it will copy the "Command Arguments" sentence.
5. You can hit "Ctrl+V" - Than it will paste what you have copied to the "Command Arguments" sentence.